# Django List View Sorting Bulletins

Tags: python, django

I have a ListView of bulletins I am trying to provide ordering options for. I am using a dropdown to pass a URL parameter called `sortBy`.

I have confirmed via my print statement at the end of `def get(self, request):` that the order of the `queryset` changes as expected when different values are passed to `sortBy`.

The problem I am facing is that even though the order of the `queryset` is changing as expected, this is not being reflected in `myTemp.html`. The order of the bulletins being displayed are not changing even though the order of the `queryset` is.

What is causing this behavior?

**Views.py**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BulletinList(ListView):
    model = Bulletin_VW
    template_name = 'myTemp.html'
    context_object_name = 'bulletins'
    additional_context = {}

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Bulletin_VW.objects.filter(store_id=self.additional_context['storeID'],
                                                   entity_id=self.additional_context['entityID'])
        ordering = self.get_ordering()
        queryset = queryset.order_by(ordering)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = super(BulletinList, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.update(self.additional_context)
        return context

    def get_ordering(self):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('sortBy', 'Name')
        sortDict = {'Name': 'author', 'Date-Newest': '-capture_date', 'Date-Oldest': 'capture_date'}
        ordering = sortDict.get(ordering)
        return ordering

    def get(self, request):
        if not validate_user_session(request.user.id):
            return redirect('newSession')
        currentSession = Current_Session_VW.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)[0]
        storeID = currentSession.store_id
        entityID = currentSession.entity_id
        entStore = currentSession.entity_store_name
        balance = get_balance(storeID, entityID)
        self.additional_context['add1'] = add1
        self.additional_context['add2'] = add2
        self.additional_context['add3'] = add3
        self.additional_context['add4'] = add4
        self.additional_context['sys_bulletins'] = Bulletin_System_VW.objects.all()
        self.additional_context['add5'] = add5
        print(self.get_context_data())
        return render(request, 'myTemp.html', self.get_context_data())
```

**myTemp.html excerpt**

```
    {% for bulletin in bulletins %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ bulletin.author }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ bulletin.capture_date|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'bulletin-detail' bulletin.bulletin_entity_store_id %}">{{ bulletin.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ bulletin.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: you need to send ajax request to get the new queryset order then render that using Jquery or JS in your select input.

Comment: Thank you - when you say 'get the new queryset order', what would the ajax request return? Since the queryset order is pythonic, I'm not sure the about the best way to return it via ajax in a way that I could easily sort by date, author, etc...

Comment: Should I return a Json object of bulletin ids, and set each div to have a corresponding id - then loop through the object rearranging the divs? Seems like their should be a more django-friendly approach to this...